# Setting netrw like NERDTree

Tags: vim, netrw

1. I used `nmap <silent> <f2> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>` to toggle nerdtree window. How can I do the same with netrw?
2. nerdtree window is not shown in the buffer list(`:ls`). netrw is listed in the buffer list. How can I make it not listed?
3. `:bn` command works but `:bp` command does not work in the netrw window. Is this a bug?

Comment: Do not forget to look at preview before posting question or answer. You got all `<...>` constructs missing.

Comment: I would complement/put together Nicks answer with: "resize" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/toggle-explorer-window/26029#26029

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The 'Vexplore' command opens a vertical directory browser. You can build on this by adding the following code to your .vimrc file to toggle the vertical browser with Ctrl-E (for example):

```
" Toggle Vexplore with Ctrl-E
function! ToggleVExplorer()
  if exists("t:expl_buf_num")
      let expl_win_num = bufwinnr(t:expl_buf_num)
      if expl_win_num != -1
          let cur_win_nr = winnr()
          exec expl_win_num . 'wincmd w'
          close
          exec cur_win_nr . 'wincmd w'
          unlet t:expl_buf_num
      else
          unlet t:expl_buf_num
      endif
  else
      exec '1wincmd w'
      Vexplore
      let t:expl_buf_num = bufnr("%")
  endif
endfunction
map <silent> <C-E> :call ToggleVExplorer()<CR>
```

The code above tries to open the Explorer window on the left hand side of the screen at all times; I use it with multiple split vertical windows open.

[OPTIONAL] You might like to add the following lines to your .vimrc to improve the browsing experience:

```
" Hit enter in the file browser to open the selected
" file with :vsplit to the right of the browser.
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1

" Change directory to the current buffer when opening files.
set autochdir
```

Comment: After opening a file, and toggling (to close), line 7 gives an error: `E16: Invalid range: 2wincmd w`, Vim 8.0.4. Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 26):

Starting with `netrw` v150, there's `:Lexplore`, which will toggle a `netrw` window on the left-hand side.

Comment: Nice!  Much better than a custom function.

Comment: `:Lexplore` takes half of the current buffer size by default. To open a 30 character size buffer only,  you can map `Ll` as such in my `.vimrc` :  `command! Ll Lexplore | vert res 30`.

Answer (score 11):

I just did some improvements on [Nick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636941/2520275) which fixes:

- opens 100% high window (independent from window splits)
- `:Lexplore` opens it on left side, `:Lexplore!` on the right
- listing the directory of the current file (**even on remote directories**)

Put these lines to the end of your .vimrc:

```
com!  -nargs=* -bar -bang -complete=dir  Lexplore  call netrw#Lexplore(<q-args>, <bang>0)

fun! Lexplore(dir, right)
  if exists("t:netrw_lexbufnr")
  " close down netrw explorer window
  let lexwinnr = bufwinnr(t:netrw_lexbufnr)
  if lexwinnr != -1
    let curwin = winnr()
    exe lexwinnr."wincmd w"
    close
    exe curwin."wincmd w"
  endif
  unlet t:netrw_lexbufnr

  else
    " open netrw explorer window in the dir of current file
    " (even on remote files)
    let path = substitute(exists("b:netrw_curdir")? b:netrw_curdir : expand("%:p"), '^\(.*[/\\]\)[^/\\]*$','\1','e')
    exe (a:right? "botright" : "topleft")." vertical ".((g:netrw_winsize > 0)? (g:netrw_winsize*winwidth(0))/100 : -g:netrw_winsize) . " new"
    if a:dir != ""
      exe "Explore ".a:dir
    else
      exe "Explore ".path
    endif
    setlocal winfixwidth
    let t:netrw_lexbufnr = bufnr("%")
  endif
endfun
```

Suggested options to behave like NERDTree:

```
" absolute width of netrw window
let g:netrw_winsize = -28

" do not display info on the top of window
let g:netrw_banner = 0

" tree-view
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3

" sort is affecting only: directories on the top, files below
let g:netrw_sort_sequence = '[\/]$,*'

" use the previous window to open file
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
```

Comment: After opening a file, toggling gives the error: `line    8: E16: Invalid range: 2wincmd w`. In fact this gives the error whenever toggling when the explorer isn't the active window. Possible some problem with VIM8?

Comment: If you want filetype-based highlighting, check https://gitlab.com/bimlas/vim-high

Answer (score 8):

### Toggle function

Here is my version of toggle function, based on Nick's answer. Now you can use hotkey **from any pane**, not only from netrw's pane. In Nick's version it causes an error, also I did some code cleanup and remap it to Ctrl-O, because Ctrl-E is used by default to scroll down by one line.

```
" Toggle Vexplore with Ctrl-O
function! ToggleVExplorer()
    if exists("t:expl_buf_num")
        let expl_win_num = bufwinnr(t:expl_buf_num)
        let cur_win_num = winnr()

        if expl_win_num != -1
            while expl_win_num != cur_win_num
                exec "wincmd w"
                let cur_win_num = winnr()
            endwhile

            close
        endif

        unlet t:expl_buf_num
    else
         Vexplore
         let t:expl_buf_num = bufnr("%")
    endif
endfunction

map <silent> <C-O> :call ToggleVExplorer()<CR>
```

Variable "t:expl_buf_num" is global for current tab, so you can have one Explorer per tab. You can change it to "w:expl_buf_num" if you want to be able to open Explorer in every window.

### Keep focus in Explorer

Also I like to have this at my .vimrc:

```
" Open file, but keep focus in Explorer
autocmd filetype netrw nmap <c-a> <cr>:wincmd W<cr>
```

Comment: Great solution! Have you noticed the flash of the file contents before rendering the NETRW pane? Do you have an idea of what could be? Thanks again!

Comment: @betoharres this is probably due to Vim's bell. Here's how to deactivate it (set it to "visual" then tell it to do nothing) `set visualbell`
`set t_vb=`

Comment: I like your function, been using it a while! However, you don't want to remap <c-o>, that's opposite of <c-i> (pair of mappings I use a lot). Last, you remap <c-a> in any filetype, try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108005/6651927) instead!

Answer (score 7):

Actually,

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
```

works best for me.

```
 *g:netrw_browse_split* when browsing, <cr> will open the file by:
                =0: re-using the same window
                =1: horizontally splitting the window first
                =2: vertically   splitting the window first
                =3: open file in new tab
                =4: act like "P" (ie. open previous window)
                    Note that |g:netrw_preview| may be used
                    to get vertical splitting instead of
                    horizontal splitting.
```

I think the best behavior is described by option 4. By pressing enter, file is opened on the other split, avoiding an overpopulation of splits.

Comment: Yep - I now do this myself, and have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
" Toggle Vexplore with Ctrl-E

function! ToggleVExplorer()
      Lexplore
      vertical resize 30
endfunction
map <silent> <C-E> :call ToggleVExplorer()<CR>
```

*Simplify*

Answer (score 0):

As a similar and simpler aprroach to [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5636941/16213794), you could make it toggleable (and very NERDTree-like) with F9 with this in your .vimrc:

```
" ---------------------------------------------------------------

" File Explorer start

let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 15

" Toggle Vexplore with F9

map <silent> <F9> :Lexplore<CR>

" File Explorer end

" ---------------------------------------------------------------
```