# Neovim + Lua: how to use different mappings depending on file type?

Tags: lua, neovim, keymapping

I have the following lua function for mapping keys in neovim

```
local M = {}

function M.map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
    -- default options
    local options = { noremap = true }

    if opts then
        options = vim.tbl_extend("force", options, opts)
    end

    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end

return M
```

And use it for key mapping like so:

```
map("", "<Leader>f", ":CocCommand prettier.forceFormatDocument<CR>") 
map("", "<Leader>f", ":RustFmt<CR>")
```

I want to use `:RustFmt` only for `.rs` files and `:CocCommand prettier.forceFormatDocument` for all the other files.

**Is this possible to do with `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap` and if so how could I do it?**

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo , not quite. The docs on `nvim_set_keymap` says it's option can not accept `<buffer>`. https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_keymap()

Comment: Try putting a config for a specific file in the [`ftplugin`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_type_plugins) directory.

Comment: @Slava.In, Sorry I removed the flag, but the comment stays. I saw that it is not the same. But the question has be answered multiple times. There are two ways. You can use a filetype specific `autocmd` or, in my opinion better, use the `ftplugin` directory as unrealapex said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133341/can-you-have-file-type-specific-key-bindings-in-vim

Comment: I would like to know how to add the filename `local filename = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0):gsub('^.*/', '')` at the beginning of the description: ` { desc = "string" }` so I that I can debug my mappings, differentiating them from other mappings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @DoktorOSwaldo and @UnrealApex I was able to resolve the issue using `ftplugin`.

Steps:

- Create `ftplugin` directory inside `~/.config/nvim`.
- Inside `ftplugin` directory create a file `rust.lua`.
- Inside `rust.lua` import `map` util and define key mapping.

```
local map = require("utils").map

-- Format document
map("", "<Leader>f", ":RustFmt<CR>")
```

For languages other than Rust use the following command to get the full list of possible file names (`.vim` can be switched to `.lua`):

```
:exe 'Lexplore ' . expand('$VIMRUNTIME') . '/syntax'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `format` function in your `utils.lua` configuration file :

```
function M.format()
  if vim.bo.filetype == 'rust' then
    vim.cmd('RustFmt')
  else
    vim.cmd('CocCommand prettier.forceFormatDocument')
  end
```

and define your key mapping like this :

```
map("", "<Leader>f", "<cmd>:lua require('utils').format<CR>")
```

Comment: Why is it `.format<CR>` and not `M.format<CR>` ?

Comment: See the complete code un the first post, code return M as table (standard structure for a Neovim plugin in Lua).

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with the current solution, which is where the desired mapping, does not unload when changing to a new file type? So once you load a rust file, it will load the desired mappings, but if you move to a different filetype, you will still have `RustFmt` bound to `<leader>f`?

How I do it, is within lsp config; by checking if the lsp server for rust is active in the current buffer (which will only be true for rust files), and if so, to load a specific keymap.

Below, if there is server providing formatting capabilities AND the client is NOT one from the list, then use `lsp.buf.format`. Else, use `:Format<cr>` (formatter.nvim plugin)

```lua
local lsp_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    local bufopts = { noremap = true, silent = true, buffer = bufnr }
    local force_formatter = client.name == "lua_ls"
        or client.name == "tsserver"
        or client.name == "pyright"
        or client.name == "bashls"

    client.server_capabilities.document_formatting = true
    -- if lsp does not provide formatting (or has been set false, above), use formatter.nvim
    if client.server_capabilities.documentFormattingProvider and not force_formatter then
        vim.keymap.set({ "v", "n" }, "<leader>f", vim.lsp.buf.format, bufopts)
    else
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>f", ":Format<cr>", bufopts)
    end
    lsp_keymaps(client, bufnr)
    require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities()
    client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil
end
```

So in your case, you could just add an extra `if` statement, to check if the `rust-analyzer` / other `lsp client` was active, and if so to load the keymap for `RustFmt`.

This works because `on_attach` is called every time the buffer attaches to a new file.

[Here is my full lsp conf from above.](https://github.com/tjex/dotfiles/blob/65a363b5ee18a0901a61143d2a93c7b3d52566e9/.config/nvim/after/plugin/lsp.lua)